# Get dictionary key if value contains string

Tags: c#, .net

I have this Dictionary:

```
    static Dictionary<int, string> Players = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dictionary.Add(1, "Chris [GC]");
    dictionary.Add(2, "John");
    dictionary.Add(3, "Paul");
    dictionary.Add(4, "Daniel [GC]");
```

I want to get the key of values that contains "[GC]"

Any idea how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a query like below.

```
   var itemsWithGC = dictionary.Where(d => d.Value.Contains("[GC]")).Select(d => d.Key).ToList();
   foreach (var i in itemsWithGC)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ:

```
var result = Players.Where(p => p.Value.Contains("[GC]")).Select(p => p.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a more performant way of solving this issue, but it might require some refactor...

Whenever you add a new player containing `"[GC]"`, you can fill a `HashSet<int>`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> Players = new Dictionary<int, string>();
HashSet<int> gcPlayers = new HashSet<int>();

dictionary.Add(1, "Chris [GC]");
gcPlayers.Add(1);

dictionary.Add(2, "John");
dictionary.Add(3, "Paul");

dictionary.Add(4, "Daniel [GC]");
gcPlayers.Add(4);
```

So now getting all keys which have `"[GC]"` is as easy as using the whole *set* called `gcPlayers`.

This will avoid a *query* and iterate the entire dictionary to get all coincidences, while you'll avoid adding duplicates to `gcPlayers` because it's a set (i.e. *an unordered collection of unique values*).